# TypeError: video is null

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming, filestream, audio-streaming

I try to make a simple video permission projects with audio and it successfully took permission but after provide the permission it's show an error as **video is null**.
Bellow the code using JS,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Media Capture</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script>
       let constraints = {'video': true, 'audio': true} 

       navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
       .then(function(stream){
            let video = document.querySelector('video');
            video.srcObject=stream;
            video.play();
            console.log(stream)
       })
       .catch(function(err){
           console.log(err)
       })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is given in attached file:

on **Google Chrome** browser showed the bellow error,

[image]

on **Firefox** browser showed the bellow error,

[image]

**Note:** please concern on above JS code and browser error and please help me to solve it. Advanced thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your whole page please?

Comment: @Xeelley, Sure! please read the questions again. Already, I updated.

Comment: So, your mistake is clear now: you actually haven't video tag anywhere. You trynna access to nothing in `querySelector('video')` thats why `video` is `null`

Comment: @Xeelley, Thanks a lot man. solved it.